# Associated Laguerre weighted function integral

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I am trying to find the general form of the following integral:

$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-u}u^{\tau}(L_{n}^{k}(u))^2\mathrm{d}u$

Where $\tau$ is a positive integer

In one of my attempts, I used the generating function of the Associated Laguerre polynomials so that I ended up with:

$\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-u}u^{\tau}(L_{n}^{k}(u))^2z^{2j}du = \tau!\frac{1}{(1+z)^{\tau+1}(1-z)^{k-\tau+1}}$

However, I couldn't find an appropriate series for the RHS. Do you know any series that I can use or any other method that can be applied to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you are looking for a method and not for the result in itself.

Gradshteyn and Ryzhik in their famous "Table of integrals, series, products" give:(formula 7.414.12 page 845) a long explicit expression for

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x(s+(a_1+a_2)/2)}x^{\mu+\beta}L_{k}^{\mu}(a_1x)L_{k}^{\mu}(a_2x)\mathrm{d}x$$

(but maybe you already know the result you want to reach).

Comment: Thank you for referencing that! Now I at least know how the result should look like. I only knew closed forms for $\tau$ equal to $k$ and $k-1$.